# How to export Kotlin's data class list to CSV in android?

Tags: android, csv, kotlin, data-class

I am able to find method for exporting Java's list of POJO to csv but unable to find a method to export Kotlin's list of data class to CSV.

Answer (score 3):

This [can be achieved](https://gist.github.com/yamin8000/fdbe5ecae4c394c520e69f9e56608df9) using basic Kotlin instead of an external library.

data class

```kotlin
data class Category(
    val id: String,
    val name: String,
)
```

utility function

```kotlin
fun <T> csvOf(
    headers: List<String>,
    data: List<T>,
    itemBuilder: (T) -> List<String>
) = buildString {
    append(headers.joinToString(",") { "\"$it\"" })
    append("\n")
    data.forEach { item ->
        append(itemBuilder(item).joinToString(",") { "\"$it\"" })
        append("\n")
    }
}
```

usage

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val firstCategory = Category(0, "Phone")
    val secondCategory = Category(1, "Laptop")
    val categories = listOf(firstCategory, secondCategory)
    val csv = csvOf(
        listOf("id", "name"),
        categories
    ) {
        listOf(it.id.toString(), it.name)
    }
    println(csv)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the solution offered by [this medium article:](https://medium.com/att-israel/jackson-csv-reader-writer-using-kotlin-f37ae771bd6d)

**To sum up**

You can create a simple generic function

```
import java.io.FileWriter

inline fun <reified T> writeCsvFile(data: Collection<T>, fileName: String) {
    FileWriter(fileName).use { writer ->
        csvMapper.writer(csvMapper.schemaFor(T::class.java).withHeader())
                .writeValues(writer)
                .writeAll(data)
                .close()
    }
}
```

I tested it with the following dependencies:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-csv:2.11.1
com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.12.5
```

Comment: Why is  ```writeCsvFile``` labelled ```private```?  As a result, I don't seem to be able to access it from my code and can't get it to work.  Any advice?

Comment: @SqueezeOJ it should not have been private - sorry for that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: The [Jackson library is now archived](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-csv)